# Starts with specific scene when App launch from background iOS

Tags: ios

I wonder how to launch the App from background with specific scene instead of always starts with launch screen or main.storyboard's initial ViewController.

For Example, if the user was viewing the profile scene and then make the app go to background from there, I would like to launch the same profile scene(without reloading or the profile pictures, bio, etc) the next time the user bring the app to the foreground.

Now the case is that the App always start with the launch screen and or the information that was loaded before went away.

How can I **remember** the specific scene when App enters background? By the way, I noticed this issue when I refractored the storyboard.

Answer (score 2):

That's exactly what state restoration is for!

State restoration is a feature in iOS that lets a user return to their app in the exact state in which they left it – regardless of what’s happened behind the scenes.

You can enable it from your appDelegate by overriding application:shouldSaveApplicationState: and application:shouldRestoreApplicationState:
and having them returning true.

Then you will have to apply restorationIdentifier to your viewControllers (and yes, you can do it from the storyboard :) ). Doing so will allow your user to come back to the very screen / screen hierarchy they were when they last left... 
You will however have to handle the logic the the data that need be displayed. In your viewController subclass, you can override encodeRestorableStateWithCoder: and decodeRestorableStateWithCoder: to store and then retrieve your data to display from the coder.

find the Apple doc here : https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/PreservingandRestoringState.html

And a Ray Wenderlich (love the man!) here : https://www.raywenderlich.com/117471/state-restoration-tutorial

Comment: Please don't just post off-site links as an answer. An answer should include at least some basic information that stands on its own. Links go bad or disappear making an answer like this no use for future readers.

Comment: Thanks, let me take a look.